# change layout box of chat android

Tags: android, layout, chat

I try to change the layout of cat in a box android application but it does not work for all
i want to display tne interface like this :

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OWv-yQxf0gs/UM3lQ5zfJRI/AAAAAAAAANs/aewZXGcUQ-I/s1600/Screenshot_messages.png]

but he display like this:
[image: http://www.irc-junkie.org/files/Yaaic_first_query.png]

the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/speech_bubble_green"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the  java code:

```
public class MessageActivity extends Activity
{
    /**
     * On create
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.message);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(
            getIntent().getExtras().getString(Extra.MESSAGE)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: **1** - you need some graphic resources. **2** - All the messages are items of a ListView. **3** - There's more code and logic behind a messaging app...

Answer (score 0):

You have generated view is buuble chat view,you need chat nine patch image. if you want to expole idea to see this link

https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Android-Speech-Bubble

http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html